# How to compare float in GLSL scripts?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

In my GLSL script i would like to compare float like this :

```
uniform float _Highlights;

if _Highlights <> 1 { doHighlights(...); }
```

but as `_Highlights` is a float I m afraid that `if _Highlights <> 1` will always return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fist of all, the "not equality" operator in GLSL is `!=` and the condition has to be in parentheses. The correct syntax in GLSL would be:

```
if (_Highlights != 1.0)
{ 
    doHighlights(...); 
}
```

If you want to to check if `_Highlights` is a value near to 1.0, then you have to use an epsilon value:

```
const float eps = 0.001;
if ( abs(_Highlights - 1.0) > eps )
{
    doHighlights(...); 
}
```